# How can I estimate the size of a text when the text has HTML decoded string in it?

Tags: ios, swift

Up until now I have been using this method to estimate the height and width of text inside my collection view to set cell height and width and height of chat bubbles.

```
func estimateFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
        let size = CGSize(width: 230, height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]
        let frame = NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
        return frame
    }
```

But the text I get from the backend has html encoded strings. So the a single quote becomes ' and so on. How can I estimate the frame for the text for the actual characters and not the html encoded strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first decode the html encoded string and them calculate the height of the string

```
extension String {

init?(htmlEncodedString: String) {

    guard let data = htmlEncodedString.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return nil
    }

    let options: [String: Any] = [
        NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
        NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
    ]

    guard let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) else {
        return nil
    }

    self.init(attributedString.string)
}}
```

use this extension like

```
let decodedString = String(htmlEncodedString: encodedString)
```

Comment: How can you combine your code with my code? I have specified font size and options such as NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin)